# Changing the order of TOC entries

Tags: table-of-contents

I am typesetting lecture notes in which I want to keep in chronological order and I've got the problem that there is something which belongs to chapter 2 after chapter 3.

I would like the table of contents entry of chapter 2 to be cohesive, but right now it looks like

[image: TOC-old]

while I intend it to look like

[image: TOC-new]

The inline code is as follows:

```
\documentclass{book}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Lorem 1}         % first chapter

\null\clearpage
\setcounter{page}{38}
\chapter{Lorem 2}         % second chapter
\section{Dolor sit}
\section{Amet consetetur}
\section{Adipisci elit}
\section{Sed eiusmod}     % fourth section

\null\clearpage
\setcounter{page}{52}
\chapter{Lorem 3}         % third chapter
\section{Dolor sit}
\section{Amet consetetur}
\section{Adipisci elit}
\section{Sed eiusmod}     
\section{Tempor incidunt} 
\section{Ut labore}

\null\clearpage
\setcounter{page}{74}
\setcounter{chapter}{1}
\chapter{Lorem 2 Encore}  % second chapter again
\setcounter{section}{4}
\section{Tempor incidunt} % fifth section

\null\clearpage
\setcounter{chapter}{3}
\chapter{Lorem 4}         % fourth chapter
\section{Dolor sit}
\end{document}
```

Any ideas on how to change the order of entries would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hard to say without looking at your code. Please provide a minimal example.

Comment: @Sora. - I've taken the liberty of augmenting your code snippets into a compilable example. Feel free to modify it further to suit your objectives.

Comment: You could use `\addcontentsline` earlier to add the contents for the out-of-order sections and then prevent TeX writing a toc entry when you actually typeset them e.g `\chapter[]{Chapter title}`, I think. (Or does this add a numbered entry with no content?)

Comment: I don't know but I just solved the problem myself, see below, but thanks anyway!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following is perhaps a bit more manageable in the long run:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{refcount}% http://ctan.org/pkg/refcount
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Lorem 1}         % first chapter

\null\clearpage
\setcounter{page}{38}
\chapter{Lorem 2}         % second chapter
\section{Dolor sit}
\section{Amet consetetur}
\section{Adipisci elit}
\section{Sed eiusmod}     % fourth section
\addtocontents{toc}{%
  \protect\contentsline {section}{%
    \protect\numberline {\getrefnumber{sec:tempor-incidunt}}\protect\ignorespaces Tempor incidunt}{\getpagerefnumber{sec:tempor-incidunt}}}

\null\clearpage
\setcounter{page}{52}
\chapter{Lorem 3}         % third chapter
\section{Dolor sit}
\section{Amet consetetur}
\section{Adipisci elit}
\section{Sed eiusmod}
\section{Tempor incidunt}
\section{Ut labore}

\null\clearpage
\setcounter{page}{74}
\setcounter{chapter}{1}

\begingroup
\renewcommand{\addcontentsline}[3]{}
\chapter{Lorem 2 Encore}  % second chapter again
\setcounter{section}{4}
\section{Tempor incidunt} % fifth section
\label{sec:tempor-incidunt}
\endgroup

\null\clearpage
\setcounter{chapter}{3}
\chapter{Lorem 4}         % fourth chapter
\section{Dolor sit}
\end{document}
```

The idea is to write the content-entry in your document at the place similar to where you want it to appear in the ToC. It uses [`refcount`](http://ctan.org/pkg/refcount) to extract both the section and page number associated with a *reference* to the section that is placed later in the document. The adjustment to `\addcontentsline` is meant to locally remove the ToC-writing capability for the oddly-placed chapter/section.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is awesome. However I should have noted I am using the `hyperref` package which redefines `\addtocontents` to use one more parameter so it wouldn't compile at first and when I added an empty parameter, the hyperlink was broken. But I was able to make it work by adding `\label{ch:tempor-incidunt}` after `\chapter` and putting `{section.\getrefnumber{ch:tempor-incidunt}.\getrefnumber{sec:tempor-incidunt}}` into the `\addcontents` parameters. Now it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Got it but gonna post it anyway in case someone might need this one day.

I looked up the definition of `\tableofcontents` in the document class file `scrreprt.cls`

```
\newcommand*\tableofcontents{%
    \if@twocolumn
      \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
    \else
      \@restonecolfalse
    \fi
    \chapter*{\contentsname
        \@mkboth{\contentsname}{\contentsname}}%
    \@starttoc{toc}%
    \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
    }
```

and figured out that `\@starttoc{toc}` is the TeX macro which generates the ToC content.

So I ran `\tableofcontents` as usual, manually edited the corresponding .toc file and included it this way:

```
\makeatletter
    \if@twocolumn
      \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
    \else
      \@restonecolfalse
    \fi
    \chapter*{\contentsname
        \@mkboth{\contentsname}{\contentsname}}%
%    \@starttoc{toc}%
    \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
\makeatother
\input{script.toc}
```

Now it looks exactly as I intended:

[image: Got it]

Comment: I think you should (in case you haven't already done so) upvote and accept @Werner's answer. His solution is more flexible and doesn't require you to hand-edit the `.toc` file or have to remember to disable `\@starttoc`.

Comment: @Mico Now that I saw his answer, I did upvote and accept it. It didn't work right away and caused the document to fail to compile but that was my fault since I should've noted my document uses the `hyperref` package. However, I was able to tweak it and make it work, as I noted in the comment under his answer.