# Changing order of TOC entries automatically

Tags: table-of-contents, cross-referencing, tocloft

I essentially want to achieve the same as [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/193463/changing-the-order-of-toc-entries) question. However, unlike the solution on that post, I cannot afford to do it manually, it needs to be performed automatically

I have defined a `\problem` and `\solution` command, which work as shown in the example below. Adding a new solution with a reference to a problem will match up the numbers, and all is well and good. Using `tocloft`, I have also managed to generate a TOC-style "List of Problems".

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks=true,
  linkcolor=black
}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}

\definecolor{darkgreen}{RGB}{0, 180, 0}

% Create the "List of Problems" object
\newlistof{problems}{prob}{List of Problems}
% Create the look of the problem and solution boxes
\newtcbox{\problembox}{on line,
                    colframe=red,
                    colback=red!20,
                    boxrule=1pt,
                    arc=4pt,
                    boxsep=0pt,
                    left=2pt,
                    right=2pt,
                    top=2pt,
                    bottom=2pt}
\newtcbox{\solutionbox}{on line,
                    colframe=darkgreen,
                    colback=darkgreen!20,
                    boxrule=1pt,
                    arc=4pt,
                    boxsep=0pt,
                    left=2pt,
                    right=2pt,
                    top=2pt,
                    bottom=2pt}
% Create the counter that keeps track of the problem number
\newcounter{problemnb}
% Create the main \problem and \solution commands. These will:
% 1. Print out the problem/solution boxes with the correct number (kept track of by the "problemnb" counter)
% 2. Add a line to the "List of Problems" (with the name given in the optional argument)
% Problems and solutions are linked by the \label-\ref pairs (as with figures e.g.)
% \problem[problem name (optional)]{problem reference}
\newcommand{\problem}[2][Problem \theproblemnb]{%        
    \newcounter{problem#2counter}
    \refstepcounter{problemnb}%
    \problembox{\color{red}\textbf{PROBLEM \theproblemnb}\label{#2}}
    \addcontentsline{prob}{section}{#1}
}
% \solution[solution name (optional)]{problem reference} (solution name defaults to "Solution" without number)
\newcommand{\solution}[2][Solution]{{%
    \hypersetup{linkcolor=darkgreen}
    \stepcounter{problem#2counter}
    \solutionbox{\color{darkgreen}\textbf{SOLUTION \ref{#2}.\the\value{problem#2counter}}}
    \addcontentsline{prob}{subsection}{#1}}
}
    
\begin{document}
\listofproblems

\problem[First problem]{prob:first} This is the first problem encountered. \\
\solution[Solution to first problem]{prob:first} I fixed it somehow. \\
\solution[Another solution to first problem]{prob:first} Found an even better fix. \\
\\
\problem[Another problem]{prob:another} Oh dear, another problem has arisen. \\
\solution[Good solution to second problem]{prob:another} This is a great fix for it, though. \\
% All good up to now
\solution[Solution to the first problem]{prob:first} This is a solution to the first problem, but it will appear in the LoP as a solution to the second.
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the code.]

The issue now is that any solutions to a previous problem that are placed after a subsequent `\problem` command will be placed under that new problem in the LoP. This is obviously undesired.

I can see two potential solutions:

1. Use the `\label` and `\ref` system already in place to somehow tell the LoP which subsections to put under which sections.
2. Look through the whole document at the very start to make a list of all the problems and their corresponding solutions, to then create the whole LoP "manually" (using a macro of course) with the sections and subsections in the correct places.

The problem now is that I am not knowledgeable/skilled enough to implement either of these. I have found ways of manually creating a TOC (as required for strategy 2), but I would have to find a way of making a list of sections and subsections at the very start of the document.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

P.S: I'm not steadfast on using `tocloft`, it's simply what was easiest for what I wanted to do up until now.

Comment: I guess that an approach could be: let the compiler write the info in separate auxiliary files (via `\newwrite`, `\openout`, and `\immediate\write` or `\write` commands), and then `\input` these files at some point. (If the problems were many, you could need `morewrites` package)

Comment: Will the compiler "read" through the entire file at the beginning, allowing all of the problems to be written? Currently my problem is that the call to ``\listofproblems`` has to come at the beginning, before any problems are created. (Sorry if this is a basic question: while I've used LaTeX for many years, this is my first time delving deeper than just surface-level, common use)

Comment: The compiler would read while compiling, and write the entries in some auxiliary files (e.g. one for each problem). Then, you could use them at the beginning of the next compile. It's the same logic of `\tableofcontents` and of mechanisms to create cross-references (that's why you need to compile twice to create a table of contents).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a way to do this using Expl3 property lists and sequences to keep track of the data. We create a property list of problem labels and titles, and a corresponding sequence of keys to keep track of their order.

Whenever a new problem is created, it creates a new sequence based on the problem label and this sequence will hold the titles of each of the solutions to that problem.

Finally we create a command to run at the end of the document to add all of the problems and solutions to the List of Problems.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks=true,
  linkcolor=black
}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}

\definecolor{darkgreen}{RGB}{0, 180, 0}
\ExplSyntaxOn
% Property list of problem labels (key) and titles (value)
\prop_new:N \l_PeterPawn_problems_prop
% Since property lists aren’t ordered, we also keep track of the keys in order using a sequence
\seq_new:N \l_PeterPawn_problems_seq
% Add a warning for duplicate keys
\msg_new:nnnn {PeterPawn}{key-exists}{\\This\ problem\ is\ already\ defined!}{Help\ text\ here.}
% command to add a solution for a particular problem
\NewDocumentCommand{\addsolution}{mm}{
    \seq_gput_right:cn {l_PeterPawn_#1_solutions_seq} {#2}
    }
% command to add a problem to the problem property list and sequence
\NewDocumentCommand{\addproblem}{mm}{
    {\prop_get:NnNTF \l_PeterPawn_problems_prop {#1} \l_tmpa_tl
    {\msg_warning:nn { PeterPawn } { key-exists }}
    {\prop_gput:Nnn \l_PeterPawn_problems_prop {#1} {#2}
     \seq_gput_right:Nn \l_PeterPawn_problems_seq {#1}
    }}}
    
% Create the main \problem and \solution commands. These will:
% 1. Print out the problem/solution boxes with the correct number (kept track of by the "problemnb" counter)
% 2. Add a line to the "List of Problems" (with the name given in the optional argument)
% Problems and solutions are linked by the \label-\ref pairs (as with figures e.g.)
% \problem[problem name (optional)]{problem reference}
% Modified to use the \addproblem and \addsolution code
\NewDocumentCommand{\problem}{O{Problem \theproblemnb}m}{%        
    \newcounter{problem#2counter}
    \seq_new:c {l_PeterPawn_#2_solutions_seq}
    \refstepcounter{problemnb}%
    \problembox{\color{red}\textbf{PROBLEM\ \theproblemnb}\label{#2}}
    \addproblem{#2}{#1} 
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\solution}{O{Solution}m}{{%
    \hypersetup{linkcolor=darkgreen}
    \stepcounter{problem#2counter}
    \solutionbox{\color{darkgreen}\textbf{SOLUTION\ \ref{#2}.\the\value{problem#2counter}}}
    \addsolution{#2}{#1}
}}

% This command must appear at the end of the document text!
\NewDocumentCommand{\makeprobscontents}{}{
    \seq_map_function:NN \l_PeterPawn_problems_seq \PeterPawn_addcontents:n}

% function to map problems and solutions to the list of problems    
\cs_new_protected:Nn \PeterPawn_addcontents:n {
        \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {#1}
        \prop_get:NnN \l_PeterPawn_problems_prop {#1} \l_tmpb_tl
         \addcontentsline{prob}{section}{\l_tmpb_tl}
        \seq_map_function:cN {l_PeterPawn_#1_solutions_seq} \PeterPawn_addsolutions:n
}
% function to map solutions to the list of problems
\cs_new_protected:Nn \PeterPawn_addsolutions:n {
    \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {#1}
    \addcontentsline{prob}{subsection}{\l_tmpa_tl}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

% Create the "List of Problems" object
\newlistof{problems}{prob}{List of Problems}
% Create the look of the problem and solution boxes
\newtcbox{\problembox}{on line,
                    colframe=red,
                    colback=red!20,
                    boxrule=1pt,
                    arc=4pt,
                    boxsep=0pt,
                    left=2pt,
                    right=2pt,
                    top=2pt,
                    bottom=2pt}
\newtcbox{\solutionbox}{on line,
                    colframe=darkgreen,
                    colback=darkgreen!20,
                    boxrule=1pt,
                    arc=4pt,
                    boxsep=0pt,
                    left=2pt,
                    right=2pt,
                    top=2pt,
                    bottom=2pt}
% Create the counter that keeps track of the problem number
\newcounter{problemnb}
    
\begin{document}

\listofproblems

\problem[First problem]{prob:first} This is the first problem encountered. \\
\solution[Solution to first problem]{prob:first} I fixed it somehow. \\
\solution[Another solution to first problem]{prob:first} Found an even better fix. \\
\\
\problem[Another problem]{prob:another} Oh dear, another problem has arisen. \\
\solution[Good solution to second problem]{prob:another} This is a great fix for it, though. \\
% All good up to now
\solution[Solution to the first problem]{prob:first} This is a solution to the first problem, and it will appear correctly now in the LoP as a solution to the the first problem as desired!.

% Need to issue this command at the end of the document
\makeprobscontents
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Very good answer, thank you. Tiny nitpick for completeness: I have had to add `\ ` between `PROBLEM` and `\theproblemnb` in the definition of the `\problem` command, as it seems to not recognize the whitespace on its own (likewise for the `\solution` command)

Comment: @PeterPawn Sorry about that. `ExplSyntaxOn` ignores spaces by design, which means you don't get any spurious spaces in commands, but at the expense of requiring explicit spaces when you do want them. I've updated the code.